# Need help writing a program that converts a text file to a html form

Tags: java, html

I need to convert a .txt file to html text, where the first line is changed to have `<h1> </h1>` around it and the rest is wrapped in `<p> </p>` so for example I read a .txt file that says:

```
chapter 1

this is a sentence
```

it would output:

```
<h1>chapter 1</h1>

<p>this is a sentence</p>
```

public class InputStream
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
FileInputStream filestream;
BufferedReader reader;
FileOutputStream output;
String firstline;
String body = "<p>";
String line;

try{
    filestream = new FileInputStream("Anna.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filestream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    firstline = reader.readLine();
    firstline = firstline.substring(0, firstline.length()-1); //chop off the newline
    firstline = "<h1>" + firstline + "</h1>\n";


    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        body = body + line;
    }


    body = body + "</p>";

     String result = firstline + body;
     reader.close();
     reader = null;
     filestream = null;

 }
 catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println(e);
     }

}
```

}

I can't get it to output? Any ideas

Comment: I'd suggest you google MarkDown, that's pretty close to what you want.

Comment: I cant get anything to output

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a [Buffered Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), using its readLine() method to read one line outside of the loop (the first line) into a string and concatenating that with your `<h1>` and `</h1>`. Then, before and after a loop you'd add the `<p>` and `</p>` tags, adding the rest of the file inside of the loop, like so:

```
InputStream filestream;
BufferedReader reader;
String firstline;
String body = "<p>";
String line;


filestream = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filestream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

firstline = reader.readLine();
firstline = firstline.substring(0, firstline.length()-1); //chop off the newline
firstline = "<h1>" + firstline + "</h1>\n";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  body = body + line;
}
body = body + "</p>"

String result = firstline + body;

// Done with the file
reader.close();
reader = null;
filestream = null;
```

I didn't test this but it should be a rough analogue to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I messed around with what you provided but I cannot get anything to output, any ideas? thanks

Comment: Well, this code does nothing with "result", so presumably you'd write that to whatever file you want to use.